# Selecting features based on relative distances between features in single shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, proximity

I have a set of polygons within a single shapefile. I want to keep only polygons, which are located >500 meters from another polygons in the same shapefile.

I thought to apply NEAR Tool in ArcGIS to measure the NEAR distances and then Select the features located > 500m. However, the NEAR Tool measures the closest distances from one feature to another feature only if I have two shapefiles.

Is there a way how to select features based on near distances in within a single shapefile?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 with Spatial Analyst licence.

Answer (score 4):

I think the solution is:

1. Run [Generate Near Table tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) with the Search Distance of 500
   metres and unticking Find only closest feature option, and
2. Use Standard Join with *Keep only matching records option* as
   joining the the ObjectID (or FIDs) field with NEAR_FID field

Comment: Cool, I did not realize that I can run the Near tools for a single shapefile: to set the shapefile as Input and Near Feture at the same time.. I couldn't figure out what is a "Standard Join" within Builder, so I just used the Near tool and Select tool to gain my goal. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @fatih_dur I realized that it is possible to use the same features in the Near Tool (spatial analysis) as the Input and Near feature

[image]

Thus I created a model in ModelBuilder where I firstly measure the distances between polygons of the single feature class. Then I just select polygons more then 500 m from each other: NEAR_FID > 500 m.

[image]